# How to hosting by denwer, when ip is closed

Tags: hosting

I have a renamed my folder by my ip adress ipv4 and for me and others who are in local can enter to the site, but others that are not local or other country cannot enter to my server writing my ip like http:http://192.168.0.102/ how can i open the access to my denwer?

http:http://192.168.0.102/ - can you enter here and tell me what the problem please?, why the access is denied??, how can i see what programm or computer are blocking my ip?, if we have one main computer, how can i make the access to my where the denwer is?

sorry for my poor english, but i need help, thanks!!!

Comment: Read up on public and private IPs. 192.168.* will never be routed outside a private network.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.x.x are private networks, you can not reach them whitout being in the LAN.

If you want to "open" your local server to the Internet, you have to add a NAT rule in your routeur/firewall.

Then, you'll be able to reach your webserver via your public IP address.

Comment: There's a lot of examples and how-to on Internet.